# Is it possible to temporarily increase dev sandbox 10 MB limit?

Tags: limits, sandbox

1. we are importing test data and hit our 10MB limit before migrating to our prod org which has 65GB limit. Is there any way to get additional 10MB for 1 week ?
2. At the top of our storage usage are record types 'config values' and 'config options' consuming nearly 3MB. We are not using this directly and if we could recover some of the storage it might allow us to complete our import test.
3. Also we have 1 object that I might be able to recover 1MB but I believe that deleting data through data loader would still keep it in the trash bin and not actually release the space.

Comment: Do you have a Configuration Only sandbox? That has 500MB of space available.

Answer (score 3):

They are all soft limits so I would raise a case. I regularly get dev orgs increased as an ISV - there can be some resistance at first, but they can certainly do it...

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do it  on a few occasions, and SF is pretty accommodating about stuff like this, especially since it's a one-off scenerio. Your account manager at SF should be able to facilitate this.